# Have there been any high-profile converts from Catholicism back to high-church traditions?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, conversion

There are several high-profile "defectors" (tongue-in-cheek!) or converts from high-church traditions (such as Anglicanism) to Roman Catholicism.  I am thinking in particular of G. K. Chesterton and John Henry Newman.  Are there any corresponding conversions from Roman Catholicism (or another Orthodox/Catholic tradition) to a high-church Protestant tradition, in the last two hundred years or so? (thus excluding the Protestant Reformation itself!)

Comment: Gotta VTC on the grounds of the list-ish nature of this question. It's good interesting question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has [an article on people who have converted to Anglicanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_who_have_converted_to_Anglicanism) and [a category for Catholic-Anglican conversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aConverts_to_Anglicanism_from_Roman_Catholicism). Ones specifically listed as converting to Anglicanism from Catholicism as adults include:

- [Madeleine Albright](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeleine_Albright)
- [Matthew Fox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Fox_%28priest%29)
- [Alberto Cutie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberto_Cutie)

---

- [Dinesh D'Souza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinesh_D%27Souza) said he converted from Catholicism to his wife's tradition in a Christian's vs. Atheists debate I attended a few years ago.  He still defends the Catholic Church very well.